# Is it possible to use @Resource on a constructor?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-annotations

I was wondering if it possible to use the `@Resource` annotation on a constructor.

My use case is that I want to wire a final field called `bar`.

```
public class Foo implements FooBar {

    private final Bar bar;

    @javax.annotation.Resource(name="myname")
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

I get a message that the `@Resource` is not allowed on this location. Is there any other way I could wire the final field?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the source of `@Resource`:

```
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Resource {
    //...
}
```

This line:

```
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD})
```

means that this annotation can only be placed on Classes, Fields and Methods. [`CONSTRUCTOR`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#CONSTRUCTOR) is missing.

Comment: Damn... i have read it multiple times, but missed this.. thanks! So i will fallback to @Autowire and @Qualifier then.

Answer (score 11):

To complement Robert Munteanu's answer and for future reference, here is how the use of `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` on constructor looks :

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    private final Bar bar;

    private final Baz baz;

    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    public Foo(Bar bar, @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("thisBazInParticular") Baz baz) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.baz = baz;
    }
}
```

In this example, `bar` is just autowired (i.e. there is only one bean of that class in the context so Spring knows which to use), while `baz` has a qualifier to tell Spring which particular bean of that class we want injected.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`@Autowired`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) or [`@Inject`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html). This limitation is covered in the [Spring reference documentation: Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

> @Autowired applies to fields, constructors, and multi-argument methods, allowing for narrowing through qualifier annotations at the parameter level. By contrast, @Resource is supported only for fields and bean property setter methods with a single argument. As a consequence, stick with qualifiers if your injection target is a constructor or a multi-argument method.

Comment: I used @Autowired together with the @Qualifier annotation. This because i have multiple implementations that can be wired. To express which implementation i need i used the Qualifier. In the documentation it states that it is prefered to used @Resource in this case. So i am trying to do that.

Comment: Which documentation item says that @Resource is preferred?

Comment: It is in the official documentation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html
below chapter 3.11.3 as the Tip!

Comment: Good point. In the Spring 3 documentation this was refined to mention the very issue you encountered, look for the tip in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers